# Numpy/pandas error when printing a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm getting the following error when I try to print a dataframe or try to drop the columns. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the latest version of numpy.

```
  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\Desktop\Shreyas\model histories\history_2017_50k_upsampled\semeval_2017_50k_upsampled.py", line 75, in <module>
    print(data9)

  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\.conda\envs\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 687, in __repr__
    show_dimensions=show_dimensions,

  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\.conda\envs\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 820, in to_string
    return formatter.to_string(buf=buf, encoding=encoding)

  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\.conda\envs\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 916, in to_string
    return self.get_result(buf=buf, encoding=encoding)

  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\.conda\envs\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 523, in get_result
    self.write_result(buf=f)

  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\.conda\envs\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 835, in write_result
    max_len = Series(lines).str.len().max()

  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\.conda\envs\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 11217, in stat_func
    f, name, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, numeric_only=numeric_only

  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\.conda\envs\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3891, in _reduce
    return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\.conda\envs\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 125, in f
    result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\.conda\envs\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 837, in reduction
    result = getattr(values, meth)(axis)

  File "C:\Users\IDALAB HCM - II\.conda\envs\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 39, in _amax
    return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data augmentation in python throws an error "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329219/data-augmentation-in-python-throws-an-error-int-argument-must-be-a-string-a)

Comment: No. I got this error just by trying to print the dataframe

Comment: Please add even some of your codesnippet.